# Library requires "dev-master" and a stable version

Tags: php, composer-php

I am developing an add-on (atk4/audit) for a framework (atk4/data). My basic `composer.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "library",
    "name": "atk4/audit",
    "require": {
        "atk4/data": "^1.3",
        "php": ">=5.6.0"
    }
}
```

This works fine and if `composer require atk4/audit` is used, then atk4/audit[1.0] and atk4/data[1.3] is installed.

However when attempted to use development branches:

```
{
    "require": {
        "atk4/data": "dev-develop",
        "myaddon/addon": "dev-develop"
    }
}
```

composer responds with error:

```
Problem 1
  - Installation request for atk4/data dev-develop -> satisfiable by atk4/data[dev-develop].
  - atk4/data dev-develop requires atk4/dsql dev-develop -> satisfiable by atk4/dsql[dev-develop] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
Problem 2
  - Installation request for atk4/audit dev-develop -> satisfiable by atk4/audit[dev-develop].
  - atk4/audit dev-develop requires atk4/schema dev-develop -> satisfiable by atk4/schema[dev-develop] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

**I want my library to be usable in both "stable" and "dev-develop" versions**. I have tried setting `composer.json` like this for the library:

```
{
    "type": "library",
    "name": "atk4/audit",
    "require": {
        "atk4/data": "dev-develop,^1.3",
        "php": ">=5.6.0"
    }
}
```

but, this does not work. I haven't found any mentions of this issue anywhere, I wonder if I'm on the wrong path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When defining an unstable dependency with Composer, you need to specify the minimum stability.

```
{
    "require": {
        "atk4/data": "dev-develop",
        "myaddon/addon": "dev-develop"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

You should also add `"prefer-stable": true`, otherwise all non-versionned packages in `composer.json` will be updated to the unstable branch.